# how can i access laptop through mobile without using any internet connection

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop, remoteview

I wanted to access my laptop using my android mobile. I have already accessed using Team Viewer. But it require a Internet connection. I want to access my laptop on my android mobile.

Is there any way to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your computer is running Windows you'll most likely want to use the built in Remote Desktop Protocol.

Microsoft has a free Andeoid app in the Google Play Store [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.android).

Microsoft has a FAQ page for their Android app [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn473007.aspx) which describes the necessary setup procedure.

If your computer is a Mac or running a Linux based OS you'll probably want to look into using VNC which is usually supported right out of the box although may require some configuration.